# How to troubleshoot Apex callout errors?

Tags: apex, callout

We have some Visualforce controllers that make SOAP calls to a hosted VM. Intermittently these callouts fail and we are having trouble finding the failure. When the failures do happen we can re-point the callouts to a different endpoint and have verified that the calls are leaving Salesforce. The host, however, insists the traffic is not making it to their network.

Are there any methods to available to the developer, either in Apex or JavaScript, to help diagnose the problem? Ideally I would like to be able to see where the packets are being lost in transit, e.g. being blocked at a firewall.

**Update 1**

To address questions raised below:

1. The errors we are getting are time-out errors; no response is coming back from endpoint.
2. The problem is not continuous and the system works most of the time. It also does not appear to be load related.
3. I don't think this is SSL related due to the fact that it normally works.
4. There really isn't anything to log that I can tell; the failures are just time-outs, so I don't have an error message to work with.

**To clarify:** I believe this is a network or configuration error with the hosting provider, but I do not know how to gather information from our Apex code/Visualforce pages to prove or disprove this theory.

**Update 2**

It is looking to be an issue with Salesforce. Working with a Salesforce engineer today he was able to contact the endpoint using his tools but the same calls failed from our Visualforce page.

**Update 3**

It's beginning to look a lot like governor limits; we might have too many callouts open at once.

Comment: What kind of errors are you getting?  I was working with SOAP callouts today, and I kept getting "Response Parsing Errors".  My solution is described below.  If you are having endpoint issues, Salesforce has decent Error Messages to troubleshoot this.

Comment: The logs provided by Salesforce indicate the callouts are timing out.

Comment: it sounds likely that it's an issue with the web service you are calling rather than Salesforce or your code in SF.

Comment: Yes, that's our thought, too, but the host claims the requests aren't making it to their data center. I'm trying to find out where the breakdown is.

Comment: Is the security endpoint manager willing to set up packet capture traces via a tool like WireShark on the interface where your traffic is passing through so that they can definitively rule out their device as being the culprit?

Comment: Last time they looked at the traffic on their public-facing firewall and said our requests never arrived, though our requests did make it to other test endpoints.

Comment: @MikeChale I'm seeing similar behavior with requests from SFDC to a service hosted on AWS, with timeout set at 120 seconds. I haven't been able to reproduce any timeouts with callouts to the same service originating outside of Salesforce. I plan on logging a case with support to try to get some additional debugging on the SF side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- How did you verify the callouts happened?
- Do you see any status message like 200,401, etc...?
- If your external system is in DMZ, then the external firewall may have rules to block the incoming calls.
- If your external system is secured by SSL certificates, then check if the certificates are installed properly. There are many tools available to check such as [this](http://www.digicert.com/help/) and [this](http://www.openssl.org/)
- Check the external system's log files. The log files name, location and setting differ based on the server that the application is hosted and it is too many to list here.
- Wrap your code in try catch block and log the exception and check this out in debug logs.
- Try accessing the external web services from other tools such as Soap UI or WCF Storm (for WCF based web services). You may also want to do load test to see if the failures are intermittent or continuous).
- Include thorough logging statements in your callout code and possibly create a custom log object and save the log into this custom object with complete information such as the external host, status code, message, exception message, stack trace, params passed, etc.

**Edit 1**:
The apex callouts, by default, time out at 10 seconds. Try increasing the timeout and see if you still get the errors. Check this [link](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_callouts_timeouts.htm) for more details. If you don't get errors after increasing the timeouts, then probably, there is some issue with the provider's network, but this will be hard to find without the provider's help. Try a simple ping in commandline from your workstation to see how many milliseconds it takes to ping the web service hosted with your external provider.

**Edit 2:**
If you are using direct HTTP callouts, then try setting the timeout on the http request object. For e.g. HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest(); req.setTimeout(20000); If you are using SOAP, then you need to write your client class that will utilize the system generated stub to invoke the WSDL. Typically, the class name would be xxxxPort. Here is a sample code. This example assumes you have a web service hosted elsewhere that gets called when a user's status is changed. The Update_StatePort inner class is generated by the system tool (through the 'Generate from WSDL' button) which is utilized by the custom written 'UserStatusClient' class.

```
public class UserStatusClient {
    @future (callout=true)
    public static void updateUser(string userName, Boolean isActive) {
    Boolean isSuccess = true;
    try {
        UserStatusWsdl.Update_StatusPort binding = buildService();
        UserStatusRequest.statusChange_element element = new UserStatusRequest.statusChange_element();
        Boolean flag = binding.Update_Status(element);
        isSuccess = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        isSuccess = false;
    }
    }

    private static UserStatusWsdl.Update_StatusPort buildService() {
    UserStatusWsdl.Update_StatusPort updateStatusInstance = new UserStatusWsdl.Update_StatusPort();
    updateStatusInstance.endpoint_x         = 'https://yourservername/yourwebservice';
            updateStatusInstance.timeout_x = 60000;
    return updateStatusInstance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Question updated with answers.

Comment: I'll try increasing the timeout. Pinging might not be accurate because the hosted VMs are set to be on our WAN.

Comment: I don't know if you can set the timeoutfor SOAP callouts using WebServiceCallout.invoke.  For sure using the method described in the link and Http Classes: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_restful_http.htm

Comment: Edited my answer to include sample code to set the timeout.

Answer (score 1):

Download soapUI to see *exactly* what the structure is of the SOAP Requests and Responses": http://sourceforge.net/projects/soapui/files/.

I was doing this very same task today because I was having issues because our WSDL didn't generate all of our classes and subclasses correctly.  Here's what I did any why:

1. Downloaded soapUI
2. Created a new `soapUI` project, attached the WSDL I used in Salesforce.
3. Then, I tested some of the methods.  It's really easy, you just click on the method, then double click the "Request 1" that appears below the clicked method.  A Request SOAP message appears, I filled out the appropriate values, and I clicked the *green arrow* to submit the request.
4. The response appears, and I used it to trouble shoot the structure of my response classes in Salesforce.

Comment: The problem isn't the requests or responses; the callouts work the majority of the time. The problem is that we intermittently get outages and cannot determine where the problem is.

Comment: well, that's quite a different difficulty compared to what I faced.  What kind of errors are being thrown?  Like no response.   Maybe this'll help: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/11742/soap-callout-fails-silently?rq=1